# when using powershell inline script in Yaml file I get error "while parsing a block mapping did not find expected key"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Yaml is really frustrating to work with, I exported as YAML from an azure devops release pipleine and each time i insert this code into my yaml file and run it Azure devops always says "error -while parsing a block mapping did not find expected key" . Is someone able to help on how to include inline powershell scripts in yaml as the export yaml option in Azure Devops is useless

```
 - task: AzurePowerShell@5
   displayName: 'test inline script in yaml'
   inputs:
   azureSubscription: 'azuresubscriptionid'
   ScriptType: InlineScript
   Inline: |
     # Setting Variables
     $var1 = "1!
     Write-Output $var1
   preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0
```

Comment: You know you've got a missing end-quote on the line where you define $var1? That's not what's causing your current error, but you'll be wanting to fix it next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below the correct script:

```yaml
  - task: AzurePowerShell@5
    displayName: 'test inline script in yaml'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'azuresubscriptionid'
      ScriptType: InlineScript
      Inline: |
        # Setting Variables
        $var1 = "1"
        Write-Output $var1
      preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0
```

There is an additional indent after `inputs:`

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops).

[Online Validator](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator)

[image]

Thanks to @vince-bowdren regarding the typo in the script.

Comment: i just tried that and same error

Comment: @itye1970 Please check it online here: https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator/743d9f

Comment: @vince-bowdren I fixed the mentioned typo in script

Comment: ok it passes validation but when it runs i get Input required: ConnectedServiceNameARM

Comment: ok sorted its working!